# visual studio 2017 could not identify platform on calculating code metrics with dotnet core solutions

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, code-metrics

I'm receiving error on code analysis with visual studio 2017 on dotnet code projects. I have to say that in other projects everything is ok.

I searched but nothing special to solve this error. the exact error is:

> Message: An error occurred while calculating code metrics for target
>   file
>   'E:\Shokri\Project\Kalgram\Kavenegar\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Kavenegar.dll'
>   in project Kavenegar. Could not identify platform for
>   'E:\Shokri\Project\Kalgram\Kavenegar\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Kavenegar.dll'.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Code metrics is not available for dotnet core projects yet. The error message is terrible. You can vote for the feature using the links below:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/33459643--netcore-code-metrics

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351625/netcore-code-metrics.html

Comment: Code Metrics for .NET Core are now available in VS2019.

Answer (score 3):

Code Metrics for .NET Core are now available in VS2019.
[image]